# Microsoft Edge "Access Denied" when using firebase.auth().SignInWithEmailAndPassword

Tags: firebase, uwp, microsoft-edge

This code on MS Edge returns a "*SCRIPT7002: XMLHttpRequest: Network Error 0x80070005, Access denied.*" error:

```
firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then(function(user) {

}, 
function(error) {
    // this is executed with auth/network-request-failed error code
});
```

It works on Chrome and Firefox and it's intended to be embedded in a WebView of an UWP app, so it's running locally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please ensure you have checked the **Private Networks (Client & Server)** capability in UWP app's Package.appxmanifest file. Ref: [Enable device capabilities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/devices-sensors/enable-device-capabilities)

This is also been mentioned in here: [WinJS.xhr: Network Error 0x2efd, Could not complete the operation due to error 00002efd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13176300/winjs-xhr-network-error-0x2efd-could-not-complete-the-operation-due-to-error-0)

[image]

And there may be SSL certificate valdiation issue, please check out this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33095348/5254458

**---Update(03/24/2017)---**

We created a firebase web application and found the same exception in IE Edge on **Windows 10 Build 14393**. There are lots of feedbacks on this in [here](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/?page=1&q=SCRIPT7002%3A%20XMLHttpRequest%3A%20Network%20Error).

Based on internal message, **this issue has been fixed from OS build 14951(Or earlier). We confirmed that this has been resolve on Windows Insider Preview Build 15058.0**, see screenshot:

[image]

**Welcome to join [Windows insider](https://insider.windows.com) and try the latest insider preview SDK.**

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I had already tried to check Private Networks and it didn't solve the problem. About the SSL certificate, I don't know which certificate I have to add in the project. Could you explain this?

Comment: Thanks for the info @FranklinChen-MSFT! That sounds right because my OS version is 14393.953. But I'm not sure about upgrading to Preview because this is my work station, is Insider stable enough to work with it? And if not, do you know when this update is going stable?

Comment: @LuccasClezar If you need to ensure the stable experience, I would suggest you waiting for Windows 10 Creators Update, it is coming soon https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/upcoming-features You could install a Insider preview virtual machine to experience new features

Comment: @LuccasClezar Just check the latest Release Preview version 15063.11, everything works well. The Windows 10 Creators Update is on its way:)

Comment: Hey @FranklinChen I can confirm that the issue is fixed on Edge, but I couldn't test it on a WebView yet because of another problem... But as I think that it should be solved (because UWP uses Edge rendering... right?) I'll mark the answer as accepted

Comment: @LuccasClezar UWP WebView use the same rendering engine as Edge:) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview#remarks